# Using the observation vector $ \vec{y}$ instead of the centered observation vector $ \vec{y_{d}} $ doesn't change the projection $\vec{\hat y}$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

I'm wondering why the two statements below are equal regardless of using $\vec{y}$ in deviation form/mean-deviaton/centered form or not. In other words, why isn't the result changed when you use the observation vector $ \vec{y} $ instead of the centered observation vector $ \vec{y_{d}} $.

$ \ X_d $ is the design matrix X in deviation form/mean-deviation form (containing the deviation values)/centered design matrix.

$\vec{y_{d}} $ is the observation vector $\vec{y} $ in deviation form/mean-deviation form/centered, also referred to as the centered observation vector.

$\mbox{ }\\$
$\mbox{ }\\$
$\mbox{ }\\$

$ \vec{\widehat y_d} = X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y_{d}}$

is equal to:

$ \vec{\widehat y_d} = X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y}$

$\mbox{ }\\$
$\mbox{ }\\$
$\mbox{ }\\$

Where $ X_d (X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} $ is the column space orthogonal projector P

And $\hat{\beta}=(X_d'X_d)^{-1}X_d'y_d$

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is “yhat” supposed to be $\hat y$?  If so, you can get that by writing `\hat y`.

Comment: Yeah thats right, but I didn't figure out hot to get the vector arrow at the same time as the hat, any tips?

Comment: `\vec{\hat y}`: $\vec{\hat y}$  Looks kinda silly though. You might consider using `\vec{y'}`: $\vec {y'} $ .

Comment: Want to have the hat cause ' can be confused with the transpose in this context:-) Thanks though, the first one does the trick, small hat though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\vec{y} = \vec{y_d} + \vec{1}\bar{y}$ where $\vec{1}$ is the vector of all ones.

Because $X_d^T \vec{1}=0$, $X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} (\vec{1}\bar{y}) = 0$ and therefore,

$$\begin{align*}\vec{\widehat y_d} &= X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y} \\
&= X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} (\vec{y_d} + \bar{y}1) \\
&= X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y_d} + X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} (\bar{y}\vec{1}) \\
& =X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y_d} + 0 \\
&= X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y_d}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @jibo does this help?

Answer (score 1):

To see why first lets take an ordinary regression:

$ y_i=\alpha + X_i'\beta +\epsilon_i  \space  \space  \space  \space $               (1)

Therefore we have

$\hat{y_i} = \hat{\alpha} + X_i'\hat{\beta}$

But by definition, $\hat{\alpha} = \bar{y}-\bar{X}'\hat{\beta}$ and thus

$\hat{y_i} = \bar{y} + (X_i-\bar{X})'\hat{\beta} = \bar{y} + X_d'\hat{\beta}$

Once again, take the relation:
$ \bar{y}=\alpha + \bar{X}'\beta \space \space  \space$   (2)

Subtract (2) from (1) to get

$ y_d= X_d'\beta +\epsilon_i $ Now note that if we run this regression, the coefficient on $\beta$ will be identical to the one above and

$\hat{y_d} = \hat{y_i} - \bar{y} =  X_d'\hat{\beta}$ which should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this! Had a typo in the 1st post, so \vec{\hat y} is supposed to be \vec{\hat y_d}, but it seems like you understood that.

Now I might be a little blind, but if 
$\hat{y_d} =  X_d'\hat{\beta}$

And we initially said that $ \widehat{\beta} = ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} $

So we substitute for $ \beta $ so that we end up with: $\hat{y_d} =  X_d'\hat{\beta} = X_d' (X_d^{T}X_d^{-1}) X_d^{T}$

Comment: Can't re-edit last comment cause of time limit, so this is a continuation of the last comment.

Now I can't see how $ \vec{\widehat y_d} = X_d^{T} (X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} $ becomes $ \vec{\widehat y_d} = X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y}$.

What is done in between?

Comment: It is incorrect to say that $\hat{\beta}=(X_d'X_d)^{-1}X_d'$.  $\beta$ must incorporate the y-values. So in the second case: $\hat{\beta}=(X_d'X_d)^{-1}X_d'y_d$

Comment: Aah yea that fell out through all the back and forth.
You are right, just rechecked and it makes sense cause it is the slope and the slope needs the different y values. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at this a little deeper I don't see the connection just yet, cause we know now that $\hat{\beta}=(X_d'X_d)^{-1}X_d'y_d$ and we also know that $\hat{\beta}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$. Essentialy what you showed, I believe, is that we can use the same $\beta$ for both cases. But how did we show that: $\vec{\widehat y_d} = X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y_{d}} = \vec{\widehat y_d} = X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} \vec{y}$ Or in other words, how can it be explained that changing  $\vec{y_{d}}$ with $\vec{y}$
doesn't alter the result.

Comment: Last line in last comment I meant more specifically: Or in other words, how can it be explained that *replacing $\vec{y_{d}}$ with $\vec{y}$ doesn't alter the result.

Comment: Yes, I understand your question. I don't have the time now to write it up formally, but the key to note is that if we de-mean the X variables *but not the dependent variable*, then $\hat{\alpha}$ changes but $\hat{\beta}$ will not.

Comment: Will chew on this, i might see the connection

Comment: Can't seem to get my head around this.
Would you use the advantage of idempotency? Our $ X_d  ( X_d^{T}X_d)^{-1} X_d^{T} $ should be idempotent, which could be an advantage.